# Making all the text show in a UITableView Cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I am loading an array into a UITableView and the components of the array are long.  What I want to do is customize the cells so that thier lenght will adjust to fit the text but the width will stay the same.  Right now what is happening is when the text gets too long it will just write off the cell and you will see this.

[image]

I would like to see the text hit the end of the cell and then start a new line.

My code right now looks like this.

```
@implementation CRHCommentSection
@synthesize observationTable; 

NSArray *myArray; 



- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    myArray = [CRHViewControllerScript theArray];  
    NSLog(@"%@", myArray);
    //NSArray* paths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0   inSection:1]];
   //[observationTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

   [observationTable reloadData]; 


    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.

    NSLog(@" in method 1");
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

 NSLog(@" in method 2");
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [myArray count];


}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath {

NSLog(@" in method 3");

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//cell.textLabel.text = @"Label"; 


return cell;
}
```

I also found some code that somebody else wrote for multiple lined cells but don't know how to make it automatic based on the length of my string from the array.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell"; 
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
 cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2
 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
cell.textLabel.text = @"Label';
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Multi-Line\nText";
cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

They said that you will also need to return a suitable height for the multi-line cell and that a height of (44.0 + (numberOfLines - 1) * 19.0) should work fine.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need to work with following methods

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // this method is called for each cell and returns height
    NSString * text = @"Your very long text";
    CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize: 14.0] forWidth:[tableView frame].size.width - 40.0 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    // return either default height or height to fit the text
    return textSize.height < 44.0 ? 44.0 : textSize.height;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * cellIdentifier = @"YourTableCell";

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 
                                      reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        [[cell textLabel] setNumberOfLines:0]; // unlimited number of lines
        [[cell textLabel] setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize: 14.0]];
    }

    [[cell textLabel] setText:@"Your very long text"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: But as to how to get the actuall cell to change its height is another problem.

Comment: Figured it out.  I made an int for the total number of lines each cell would have by doing int numberOfLines = ([[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] length] / 44); where I divided by 44 because that is the max number of chars on one line based off of the width of my cell.  Then I returned this: return textSize.height = (44.0 + ( numberOfLines - 1) * 19.0); And it gave me a fitting cell size for each cell based on the length of the text.

Comment: did not work for me, CGSize returns wrong height for some reason.

Comment: @BorisGafurov without seeing any of your code it is hard to help you, create new question.

Comment: exactly the same as above. height is always 18 no matter how long is the string.

Comment: @Craig numberOfLines = 0, does work as well. Then you do not have to calculate the lines.

Comment: can you update this as UILineBreakModeWordWrap is now deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at the NSString function `-(CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size`

You will have to include it in your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` function to determine the right heights.

Also, set the `numberOfLines` for your label to 0.  This allows it to adjust to whatever number of lines is needed.

Answer (score 0):

How about using UITextView in table view cell.

At first, you have to change the height of cell.

Next, you put the UITextView into the cell.

[image: ss]

[image: ss]

Off course you can do this not by IB but by code.

Comment: how would you add a textview into a cell for every component in your array? That number can vary in my case.

Answer (score 0):

For me the accepted answer worked by adding the else condition.
In my case, if condition was not getting satisfied as the `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"comment"];` was always returning cell which was not nil.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSInteger item = indexPath.item;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"comment"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                      reuseIdentifier:@"comment"];

        [[cell textLabel] setNumberOfLines:0]; // unlimited number of lines
        [[cell textLabel] setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize: 14.0]];
    }
     // added else condition
    else {
        [[cell textLabel] setNumberOfLines:0];
        [[cell textLabel] setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize: 14.0]];
    }

    [[cell textLabel] setText:commentsText[item]];

    return cell;
}
```